# Representing boolean function by a rational function

Tags: boolean-functions

What is known about the separation of minimal degrees of polynomials and that of rational functions that represent boolean functions? What is a good reference for the topic?

Comment: Can you give an example of a rational function representing a Boolean function?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I am thinking along the same lines as representation in this question http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/27042/representing-boolean-function-by-a-polynomial where $p(x)$ is replaced by $p(x)/q(x)$.

Comment: I'm not sure there are any non-trivial examples, but before thinking about it, I was interested whether you knew about any.

Comment: Exactly how is the representation defined? Specifically, do you demand that $q(x)\ne0$ for all $x\in\{0,1\}^n$, or is it sufficient if the rational function has an appropriate limit at these points?

Comment: (A case in point: $(x^3+y^3)/(x^2+y^2)$ uniquely extends to a total real-analytic function that defines $x\lor y$ on $\{0,1\}^2$, and the two polynomials have no common divisor, nevertheless they both vanish at $(0,0)$.)

Comment: Actually, if this *is* allowed, it gives a nontrivial example for the question: the function $x_1\lor\dots\lor x_n$ requires polynomials of degree $n$, but can be expressed by the degree 3 rational function $(x_1^3+\dots+x_n^3)/(x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2)$.

Comment: What is the polynomial for the OR function? (I guess you can recursively use the polynomial for $x_1 \vee x_2$)

Comment: $1-(1-x_1)\cdots(1-x_n)$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek missed the question. the rational function needs to have exact valuation at given points (should not be a limit).